# Build Gradle en Unity:

Tags: android, firebase, unity3d

Estoy intentando añadir Firebase de Google a mi proyecto Unity para Android. Por el momento solo he añadido el servicio de Firebase Analytics pero a la hora de construir el apk me sale el siguiente error:

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
E:/Aplicaciones/Java/jdk-9.0.1\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  ]
  stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

No encuentro información al respecto por ningún lado, solo algo de que puede ser por la versión del gradle como pone en esta web: [gradle_version](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-determine-java-version-from-9-0-1/24457)
En caso de ser eso, ¿cómo se actualizaría el gradle?
Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Me temo que es la versión de tu sdk, tendrás que hacer rollback al sdk8. Ultimamente el jdk9 me da muchos errores, y aún desconozco la mayoría de estos, y no he tenido tiempo para indagar al respecto.

Comment: Pues me pongo a probar a ver que tal, muchas gracias por tu rápida respuesta.

Comment: El jdk9 tiene una estructura distinta a las versiones previas. Al no seguir el esquema los ClassLoaders de varias librerías dejan de funcionar o bien marcan el jdk9 como inválido.

Comment: Efectivamente se ha arreglado con la versión 8. Muchas gracias!